# I wanted to try having different moving averages, yet it doesn't work when I copy paste them on top of each other

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

What can I do? It can't graph the last two plot smoothingLine2 and smoothingLine3. This is the code. I just added 2 and 3 at the end to distinguish from the rest. While it can plot the lengths, it won't do so with EMA/smoothing lines.

l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l

````
indicator(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)

len2 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length2")
src2 = input(close, title="Source2")
offset2 = input.int(title="Offset2", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
plot(out2, color=color.blue, title="MA2", offset=offset2)

len3 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length3")
src3= input(close, title="Source3")
offset3 = input.int(title="Offset3", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out3 = ta.sma(src3, len3)
plot(out3, color=color.blue, title="MA3", offset=offset3)



ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

typeMA = input.string(title = "Method", defval = "SMA", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="Smoothing")
smoothingLength = input.int(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")


ma2(source2, length2, type2) =>
    switch type2
        "SMA2" => ta.sma(source2, length2)
        "EMA2" => ta.ema(source2, length2)
        "SMMA (RMA)2" => ta.rma(source2, length2)
        "WMA2" => ta.wma(source2, length2)
        "VWMA2" => ta.vwma(source2, length2)

typeMA2 = input.string(title = "Method2", defval = "SMA2", options=["SMA2", "EMA2", "SMMA (RMA)2", "WMA2", "VWMA2"], group="Smoothing2")
smoothingLength2 = input.int(title = "Length2", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing2")


ma3(source3, length3, type3) =>
    switch type3
        "SMA3" => ta.sma(source3, length3)
        "EMA3" => ta.ema(source3, length3)
        "SMMA (RMA)3" => ta.rma(source3, length3)
        "WMA3" => ta.wma(source3, length3)
        "VWMA3" => ta.vwma(source3, length3)

typeMA3 = input.string(title = "Method3", defval = "SMA3", options=["SMA3", "EMA3", "SMMA (RMA)3", "WMA3", "VWMA3"], group="Smoothing3")
smoothingLength3 = input.int(title = "Length3", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing3")



smoothingLine = ma(out, smoothingLength, typeMA)
smoothingLine2 = ma(out2, smoothingLength2, typeMA2)
smoothingLine3 = ma(out3, smoothingLength3, typeMA3)

plot(smoothingLine, title="Smoothing Line", color=#f37f20, offset=offset, display=display.none)
plot(smoothingLine2, title="Smoothing Line2", color=#f37f20, offset=offset2, display=display.none)
plot(smoothingLine3, title="Smoothing Line3", color=#f37f20, offset=offset3, display=display.none)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made the change to your code.
Hope this helps

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)

len2 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length2")
src2 = input(close, title="Source2")
offset2 = input.int(title="Offset2", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
plot(out2, color=color.blue, title="MA2", offset=offset2)

len3 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length3")
src3= input(close, title="Source3")
offset3 = input.int(title="Offset3", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out3 = ta.sma(src3, len3)
plot(out3, color=color.blue, title="MA3", offset=offset3)



ma1(source, length, type1) =>
    switch type1
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

typeMA = input.string(title = "Method", defval = "SMA", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="Smoothing")
smoothingLength = input.int(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")


ma2(source2, length2, type2) =>
    switch type2
        "SMA2" => ta.sma(source2, length2)
        "EMA2" => ta.ema(source2, length2)
        "SMMA (RMA)2" => ta.rma(source2, length2)
        "WMA2" => ta.wma(source2, length2)
        "VWMA2" => ta.vwma(source2, length2)

typeMA2 = input.string(title = "Method2", defval = "SMA2", options=["SMA2", "EMA2", "SMMA (RMA)2", "WMA2", "VWMA2"], group="Smoothing2")
smoothingLength2 = input.int(title = "Length2", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing2")


ma3(source3, length3, type3) =>
    switch type3
        "SMA3" => ta.sma(source3, length3)
        "EMA3" => ta.ema(source3, length3)
        "SMMA (RMA)3" => ta.rma(source3, length3)
        "WMA3" => ta.wma(source3, length3)
        "VWMA3" => ta.vwma(source3, length3)

typeMA3 = input.string(title = "Method3", defval = "SMA3", options=["SMA3", "EMA3", "SMMA (RMA)3", "WMA3", "VWMA3"], group="Smoothing3")
smoothingLength3 = input.int(title = "Length3", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing3")



smoothingLine = ma1(out, smoothingLength, typeMA)
smoothingLine2 = ma2(out2, smoothingLength2, typeMA2)
smoothingLine3 = ma3(out3, smoothingLength3, typeMA3)

plot(smoothingLine, title="Smoothing Line", color=#f37f20, offset=offset, display=display.none)
plot(smoothingLine2, title="Smoothing Line2", color=#f37f20, offset=offset2, display=display.none)
plot(smoothingLine3, title="Smoothing Line3", color=#f37f20, offset=offset3, display=display.none)
```